# Preventing subelement from exceeding parent's height?

Tags: css, height, containers, parent-child

Given this code:

```
.yourHeaderContainer {background-color:#EEEEEE; line-height:34px; height:34px;}

.yourHeaderContainer .challengeSomeone {float:right; margin-right:10px; font-size:12px; font-weight:bold; padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;}
```

Is there any way I can prevent the child element from exceeding the line height (or height) of the parent container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do an overflow:hidden on the parent (overflow-y:hidden should work too).